# Find date column

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA and I am trying to write a macro that will find a column that contains dates in my data and select a column next to it.

Date is something like:

```
Date    output
01/02/2011  200
02/02/2011  200
03/02/2011  200
```

I have tried:

```
Sub Macro5()
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        .Find(what:=vbDate).Select
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work as expected.
Can anyone give me a solution, please?

Comment: vbDate = 7 so in your .Find statement you are searching for the number 7.  Just search for the column label ('Date') and you might limit your search to the first row.

Comment: Are you saying, you have no idea ahead of time where on the sheet the dates could be? So you have to search for dates, any dates?

Comment: And you can search search for a _format_ (at least in modern versions of excel)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, the problem is that the date column in my tables isn't allways calls 'Date'.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, at list first cell that contains date in my worksheet.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, how? I am using Excel 2010

Comment: @chrisneilsen: That is a valid answer ;) You may want to add that as an answer :)

Comment: @AndriyTkach: Do you know how to record a macro?

Comment: You can search for a format using `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "something"`, in this case `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Thank's for comments! Not to you @SiddharthRout

Comment: `Thank's for comments! Not to you @SiddharthRout –  AndriyTkach 1 min ago` - 1 For being sarcastic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a demo of searching for a Format

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngDate As Range

    ' Set reference to search range by whatever means
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ' Setup search
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

    ' Do search
    Set rngDate = rng.Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True)

    ' report result
    If Not rngDate Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Found a Date formated cell in column " & rngDate.Column
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Nicely done. Much better than looping through cells.

Comment: @sid taking my time to write a (I hope) decent answer pays off!

Comment: IMHO, Chris, that is the best way and pays off in the long run ;)

Comment: @sid like minds...  IMNSHO I wish more pepole would think like this

Comment: If anyone has doubts, show them [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) :P

Answer (score 1):

The code below searches for a date in your active sheet. As soon as it finds one, it selects the column next to it and stops.

```vb
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If IsDate(rng.Value) Then
        rng.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that searches row 2 for cells formatted as a date (assuming any date contains at least the day i.e the string `d`):

```
Dim i As Long
With Sheet1.Range("2:2")    ' or wherever you want to search
    For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
        With .Cells(1, i)
            If InStr(.NumberFormat, "d") <> 0 Then
                .Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Select
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End With
```